# How do I know if a BLE scan is ongoing?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My app is scanning for devices when in the foreground and parses the ble advertisement data and displays it. The scanning and parsing are controlled by a state machine. I'm getting frequent scan fails and hence restarting the scan. How would I check if the scan is ongoing before starting another?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you mean with "scan fails". Like exceptions, error codes etc. and where in your code the fail happens.

Comment: I'm getting callback in onScanFailed with errorCode 1

Comment: onScanFailed also returns an Int Error code.first check why its failing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()` returns true, the device is scanning.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter#isdiscovering

Comment: I know it's an old question and answer, but for me this does not work. `isDiscovering` works just for classic bluetooth. If you work wie BLE `isDiscovering` is always false. `isDiscovering` is just true, when you call `startDiscovering()`. And yeah `startDiscovering()` is for classic bluetooth.